# Android Ormlite change model field type

Tags: android, ormlite

I want to change model field types from double to BigDecimal and from String to BigDecimal ( see below ).

Old model:

```
@DatabaseField
private double val1;
@DatabaseField
private String val2;
@DatabaseField
private double val3;
```

New model :

```
@DatabaseField
private BigDecimal val1;
@DatabaseField
private BigDecimal val2;
@DatabaseField
private BigDecimal val3;
```

Should I make any changes in onUpgrade method and increase database version ? What approach should I choose to do it correct ?

For example:

1. copy val1 column to copy_val1
2. remove val1 column, and create new one ( correct column type )
3. copy data from copy_val1 to val1 column with casting
4. remove copy_val1 column

Answer (score 1):

According to [ORMLite data type docs](http://ormlite.com/data_types.shtml), `double` and `BigDecimal` aren't managed by the same ORMLite data type. Same for `String` and `BigDecimal`. So yes, you have to do the update and increase version.

In `onUpdate` you can:

1. Create new column 'val1_aux' with the correct column type
2. Update new column, taking the old value.
3. Remove old column.
4. Rename new column from `val1_aux` to `val1`

I think there is no need to create another intermediate column.

Comment: If I download databases via adb pull, there are type DOUBLEPRECISION for double, but for String and BigDecimal there is VARCHAR. Strange thing is that I am able to add another entry without any problem without doing any database migration

Comment: Of course, the migration will be done in `onUpdate` method, that will be executed when version increment is detected. Which is the problem?

Comment: as I mentioned I haven't done any migration and I can add entries to table with changed types for BigDecimal without any exceptions